# Lower bounds of the entropy function

Tags: derivatives, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, entropy

Let $H(x,p)$ be the entropy function. That is
$$H(x,p) :=x\log(\frac{x}{p})+(1−x)\log(\frac{1-x}{1-p})\quad(0<x<1,\,0<p<1)$$

A) Show if $x\neq p$ then $H(x,p) \geq 2(x-p)^2$

B) Show if $\frac{1}{2}\leq p < x$ (or if $x<p\leq\frac{1}{2}$) then $H(x,p) \geq \frac{(x-p)^2}{2p(1-p)}$

I can't seem to figure either of these out. In a preceding problem we found the first and second derivative of $H,$ which may factor into the solution, but I cannot see where. Does anyone have any idea ? I think there is something simple I am missing for both here.

Edit: Proof for (A)

First see that for $0<x<1$, $\frac{d^2H}{dx^2} = \frac{1}{x(1-x)}\geq 4$ Now, integrating both sides we see $\frac{dH}{dx} = 4x$, and integrating again we have $H \geq 2x^2 \geq 2(x-p)^2$ since $0<p<1$.

I am fairly sure the same argument applies to part (B). I thought I had it figured out, but while writing I realized my attempt was incorrect. I attempted to do roughly the same exact thing but since $2p(1-p)$ varies from 0 to 1/2, it is larger than $2(x-p)^2$.

Comment: How do the derivatives you computed earlier compare to the derivatives of these bounding functions on the other side of the inequality?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm unsure if you are offering some sort of hint, or if you are genuinely asking, but I see no connection between the two.

Comment: I'm telling you to compare the derivatives. If two functions start at the same value but one is always growing faster than the other, what conclusion should you draw?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ah yes, I just saw that for A. Thank you. However, this method wont really help me on part B, and now I am stuck on that

Comment: At least, I dont see it helping the same way it did in A.

Comment: Then I suggest you look harder.

Comment: @Ralph If you have found a proof sketch for the part $A$, I'd suggest that you write it down in the question post. Your question has some close votes , and these can be retracted if you insert that attempt into the question. I actually don't know how you did it, but once you do it I can try to help you figure out part $B$ from the argument in part $A$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon that would be great, because part B is actually harder than I thought, and my argument never ended up actually working. I attached my proof for A.

Comment: @Ralph I'm sorry that I don't see it yet, it has not appeared in the question post for me. Are you still editing it? Once you're done, I'll take a look and promise , vote to reopen if the effort is good enough. Try to get in some minor details as well, because if you reopen your question I can address you in the comments and follow it up with an answer. (Great stuff, voting to reopen!)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon sorry, was writing.

Comment: @Ralph Thank you very much. I highly appreciate you taking my feedback into account. Always remember that adding context, even that which develops across comments, into your post will help you get more attention on the site, prevent question closure, and get you a better quality of answers. I will take a look and see if I can give you a hint. +1 from me for now will do. (I have asked for reopening of the question).

Comment: @Ralph Managed to reopen the question, and you get a good answer in response. Great to see the system work well. Always remember, if your question is good it will get what it deserves!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your proof of part (A). First, you probably mean $\frac{dH}{dx} \ge 4x$, not $\frac{dH}{dx} = 4x$. But that conclusion would be valid only if $\frac{dH}{dx}$ is zero for $x=0$, which it isn't: For fixed $p$, the function decreases first and then increases with increasing $x$. The same problem is with the conclusion that $H \geq 2x^2$, and $2x^2 \geq 2(x-p)^2$ does not hold for $x < p/2$.

These problems can be solved. With $h(x) = H(x, p)$ for fixed $p$ you can show that $h(p) = h'(p) = 0$. Then $h''(x) \ge 4$ implies
$$
h(x) = h(p) + h'(p) (x-p) + \frac{h''(c)}{2}(x-p)^2\ge 2 (x-p)^2 \, ,
$$
using Taylor's theorem. You can proceed similarly for part (B): If $\frac{1}{2}\leq p < x$ then
$$
 h''(t) = \frac{1}{t(1-t)} \ge \frac{1}{p(1-p)}
$$
for $p \le t \le x$.

Here is a different approach, using an integral representation, similarly as in [Prove Positivity of a Function Involving $\log$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070703/prove-positivity-of-a-function-involving-log/4070714#4070714).

We have
$$
 H(x, p) = x\int_p^x \frac{dt}{t} + (1-x)\int_{1-p}^{1-x}\frac{dt}{t} \\
= \int_p^x  \left( \frac xt - \frac{1-x}{1-t}\right) \, dt
= \int_p^x   \frac{x-t}{t(1-t)} \, dt \, .
$$

For part (A) we use $t(1-t) \le 1/4$, that gives
$$
 H(x, p) \ge 4\int_p^x (x-t) \, dt = 2(x-p)^2 \, .
$$

(*Remark:* Yes, that works if $p \le x$ and if $p \ge x$.)

For part (B), if $\frac{1}{2}\leq p < x$ or $x<p\leq\frac{1}{2}$ then $t(1-t) \le p(1-p)$ for all $t$ in the integration interval, and therefore
$$
 H(x, p) \ge \frac{1}{p(1-p)}\int_p^x (x-t) \, dt = \frac{(x-p)^2}{2p(1-p)} \, .
$$