# Prove Positivity of a Function Involving $\log$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, inequality, logarithms

I want to prove

The function $f:(0,\infty)^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{equation}\label{key}
   f(x,y) =  \ln \left( \dfrac{1+y}{1+ x}\right) + \dfrac{x}{1+ x} \ln \left( \dfrac{x}{y}\right)
  \end{equation}
is non-negative.

My attempt was to compute   $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and then see where the zeros of the function are.

I think that works fine, but I was wondering if there was a slicker way to do it.

Comment: $\log = \log_e$?

Comment: @VIVID made a correction, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing the logarithms as integrals over $1/t$ gives
$$
 (x+1)f(x, y) = (x+1) \int_{1+x}^{1+y} \frac{dt}{t} + x \int_y^x \frac{dt}{t} = \int_x^y \left(\frac{x+1}{t+1} - \frac xt\right) \, dt \\
= \int_x^y \frac{t-x}{t(t+1)} \, dt  = \int_0^{y-x} \frac{s}{(s+x)(s+x+1)} \, ds\, ,
$$
and that is non-negative: The integrand is $\ge 0$ if $x \le y$, and $\le 0$ otherwise.

One can also see that equality holds exactly if $x=y$.

Comment: I tried to exploit integration too noticing the quantity is $f(x+1,y+1)-f(x,y)$ for $f(x,y)=x\ln(\frac yx)$ but wasn't successful. I notice you still have an $(x+1)$ wandering around that do not really cancel...

Comment: @zwim: What to you mean by “not really cancel”? Perhaps it would be more natural to define $f(x, y) =  (1+x)\ln \left( \frac{1+y}{1+ x}\right) +x \ln \left( \dfrac{x}{y}\right)$ which is equal to $ \int_x^y \frac{t-x}{t(t+1)} \, dt$.

Comment: Yes, I realize that now.

Comment: Does it assume that x,y are both non negative?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, it is given in the question that the function is defined on $(0,\infty)^2$, so $x$ and $y$ are both positive.

Comment: I still don't get how you arrived at $[y, x]$ bound from $[1+x, 1+y]$ and $[y,x]$ bounds

Comment: @Alex: $\ln(y+1)-\ln(x+1) = \int_{x+1}^{y+1} dt/t  = \int_x^y dt/(t+1)$, and $\ln(x)-\ln(y) = \int_y^x dt/t = -\int_x^y dt/t$. – Let me know if anything is wrong or unclear!

Answer (score 5):

Here is an elementary proof without calculus: Combine the logarithms and obtain
$$
f(x,y)=\ln\left[\frac{1+y}{1+x}\cdot\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{\frac{x}{1+x}}\right].
$$
We have to show that the argument of the logarithm is always $\geq 1$. This is equivalent to
$$
\frac{1+y}{1+x}\geq \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{\frac{x}{1+x}}.
$$
However, using Bernoulli's inequality and keeping in mind that $0<\frac{x}{1+x}\leq 1$ and $\frac{y-x}{x}>-1$, we have
$$
\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{\frac{x}{1+x}}=\left(1+\frac{y-x}{x}\right)^{\frac{x}{1+x}}\leq 1+\frac{y-x}{x}\cdot\frac{x}{1+x}=1+\frac{y-x}{1+x}=\frac{1+y}{1+x}
$$
and so we are done!

Comment: Very nice! (But I would not call  the use of Bernoulli's inequality a proof “without calculus” :)